# Facebook Like Button Comment Box Event

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using XFBML to load a like button into my page and I hooked an event to my button.

The problem is that the event is trigger **after** the user fill the comment box (edge-box).

I already tried to hide it with CSS but the problem still remains. The user needs to click anywhere on the page to trigger my callback function.

Here a sample of code :

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    window.location = "[URL]";
}
```

And my CSS :

```
.fb_edge_comment_widget { display: none !important; }
```

On of the solution could be to find a way to disable the comment box, but it doesn't seem possible.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Like Button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#faq) contains a way to prevent the comment box on the Like Button from appearing, or at least, outlines the conditions under which it shouldn't appear:

"If you are using the XFBML version of the Like button, users will always have the option to add a comment. If you are using the Iframe version of the button, users will have the option to comments if you are using the 'standard' layout with a width of at least 400 pixels. If users do add a comment, the story published back to Facebook is given more prominence."

[Edit: Alternative 2 below]

Another option is to not use the Like Button plugin at all and instead switch to using the new [built in Open Graph 'Like' action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/). This involves a few steps:
1. Configure your app in the Developer Dashboard to add the 'like' global action.
2. Create your own custom like button
3. Attach an API call to `https://graph.facebook.com/USERID/og.likes` to that button (with parameters `object` and `access_token`)

Given that this option would mean that you control pretty much all of the client-side code, you should have no problems at all tracking the Like action and then performing any action you want afterwards.

Comment: I just want to have a one click action. The user click on the like button then he get redirected to another page.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an additional solution that you might want to try. If not, you should still try my original solution as that should work too.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS "display: none" doesn't seem to work anymore, but setting a fixed height to the iframe is working for me:

```
iframe.fb_iframe_widget_lift {
  height: 20px !important; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Uncheck the "Send Button" while generating XFBML code for your site from this link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment box will be removed.

Comment: This is not true, the Send Button parameter merely controls whether the Send button appears alongside the Like button, nothing else.

Comment: Ok, was not he just want to remove that comment box along with the like button?

Comment: The comment box he is referring to is the one that appears after a user has clicked on the Like button, to allow them to add extra text to the story that will appear on their Timeline. The Send button is a separate issue.

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant content/promotional material to your answers. Your contributions are more than welcome, but please keep them on-topic.